# Where is the netboot image?

Tags: pxe

I  wanted to ask that I used the netboot image from the ubuntu 10.04 server for PXE Booting ubuntu 10.04 desktop edition as I didn't find the netboot folder in the ubuntu 10.04 desktop edition

The netboot image boot normally retrieves and parses the unattended file but later go in error while trying to download installer component.

Also can anyone post a link where I can find the netboot folder for ubuntu 10.04 desktop edition?

Answer (score 3):

The netboot installation method is not different between Desktop and Server for Ubuntu: you should be able to install either environment from the same installer (or, in fact, any flavour of Ubuntu).

Netboot installers are found either at

```
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/${RELEASE_CODENAME}/main/installer-${ARCHITECTURE}/current/images/
```

or

```
http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/${RELEASE_CODENAME}/main/installer-${ARCHITECTURE}/current/images/
```

depending on your architecture. I am unable to help with the anna error: my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

Netboot images are available here:

- http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/